# Expand system partition on my system disc C (Windows 7)

Tags: windows-7, windows, hard-drive, partitioning, ntfs

I have a system disc **C:** (Windows 7 is installed) and all installation program files (installed programs) on **D:** because of poor space on C:.
Now I'm stuck with this question: how to increase the space on C: ?

[http://answers.microsoft.com/](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-performance/how-to-extend-system-drive-partition-c-to-get-more/6acd8697-4292-4280-8270-049691d14598) says: 
*Windows 7 Disk Management can expand the system partition, but there must be some unallocated space next to the partition.*

I have more logical discs E, F, G and unallocated space that is OK to use, but the problem is the unallocated space is **not** next to the system disc C:.

So, what is my option? Is it possible? I need to keep alive the system and programs.

Comment: A word of warning: Moving partitions is dangerous and you must absolutely create a backup beforehand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download [Gparted](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gparted/files/gparted/gparted-0.19.0/) or [Aomei](http://www.disk-partition.com/free-partition-manager.html) or [EaseUS](http://www.easeus.com/partition-manager/).

Move your G, F and E  partitions across your unallocated space. Now your unallocated space will be next to your C partition. After this you may be able to extend C partition either by the downloaded 3rd party or your disk manager.

Comment: +1. I would use GParted to move partitions E, F and G to the end of the disk as said, but I would then use Windows Disk Manager to resize C - this is the official tool to use, at the end of the day!

Answer (score 0):

I would try using `GParted`, the Windows version to see if you can move some of the unallocated space to the `C:`. It's fairly easy to use.